# PySpark : Merge a row to its parent if single row else add the row(s) are child

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

Very new to python or handling data in large scale. I am newbie any help would be much appreciated

I have two dataframe in pyspark

```
dF1 : total order schedule

aggregatedOrderId | totalOrderQuantity | ETA  | Quantity
 xyz              | 20                 |      |
 abc              | 10                 |      |

dF2: detailed order

aggregatedOrderId | Quantity           | ETA 
 xyz              | 10                 | 08/01
 xyz              | 10                 | 08/25
 abc              | 10                 | 07/25

output should look like:

aggregatedOrderId | totalOrderQuantity | ETA   | Quantity
 xyz              | 20                 |       |
 xyz.1            |                    |  08/01| 10
 xyz.2            |                    |  08/25| 10
 abc              |  10                |  07/25| 10

when there is single child record it has to become a single row in final df and when there are multiple child they go into separate rows with {orderId.[1-9]}. the out of this has to be in a json so I tried something like this.

from pyspark.sql import Window
window = Window.partitionBy('aggregatedOrderId').orderBy('aggregatedOrderId')
resdf2 = df2.withColumn('row_id', F.row_number().over(window))
resdf2 = resdf2.withColumn('agg', F.col('aggregatedOrderId')).withColumn('newRow' ,F.concat(F.col('aggregatedOrderId'), F.lit('.'), F.col('row_id'))).drop('aggregatedOrderId').withColumnRenamed('newColumn', 'aggregatedOrderId')


df1 = df1.withColumn('agg', F.col('aggregatedOrderId'))

finaldf = df1.join(
            resdf2 .groupBy("agg")
            .agg(F.collect_list(F.struct(*resdf2 .columns)).alias("orderSplits"))
            , ["agg"], 'left').drop('agg')
```

final df would like something like, where orderSplits is an array of rows. and I write the final DF as Json file for API to use.

```
aggregatedOrderId | totalOrderQuantity | ETA  | Quantity | orderSplits
```

I am really struck on how to merge when there is single row and leave as such and give sub ids to multiple rows and then convert into json with orderSplits

Appreciate anyone helping me on this

Answer (score 1):

Check this out. I calculated single child record and multi child seperately and used union to merge them.

```
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    from pyspark.sql import functions as F
    from pyspark.sql.window import Window


    spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName('so')\
        .getOrCreate()

    sc= spark.sparkContext

    df1 = sc.parallelize([
        ("xyz", 20, '',''), ("abc", 10, '','')
    ]).toDF(["aggregatedOrderId","totalOrderQuantity", "ETA", "quantity"])

    # df1.show()
    df1_r = df1.withColumnRenamed("aggregatedOrderId", "aggregatedOrderId_par")

    w_p = Window().partitionBy("aggregatedOrderId_par").orderBy("aggregatedOrderId_par")

    w1 = Window().partitionBy("aggregatedOrderId")

    w_c = Window().partitionBy("aggregatedOrderId").orderBy("aggregatedOrderId")

    df1_1 = df1_r.withColumn("r_no", F.row_number().over(w_p))

    # df1_1.show()


    df2 = sc.parallelize([
        ("xyz", 10, '08/01'), ("xyz", 10, '08/05'),("abc", 10, '07/25')
    ]).toDF(["aggregatedOrderId","Quantity", "ETA"])

    df2_c = df2.withColumnRenamed("ETA", "ETA_c").withColumnRenamed("Quantity", "Quantity_c")\
            .withColumn("r_no", F.row_number().over(w_c)).withColumn("order_count", F.max("r_no").over(w1))


    #calculate single parent has single child
    df2_2_c_single = df2_c.filter(F.col("order_count")==1)

    # df2_2_c_single.show()

    cond = (df1_1.aggregatedOrderId_par==df2_2_c_single.aggregatedOrderId)
    df_single = df2_2_c_single.join(df1_1,cond , how ='left')

    df_single_final = df_single.select("aggregatedOrderId",  "totalOrderQuantity", F.col("ETA_c").alias("ETA"), F.col("Quantity_c").alias("quantity"))

    df_single_final.show()

    # +-----------------+------------------+-----+--------+
    # |aggregatedOrderId|totalOrderQuantity|  ETA|quantity|
    # +-----------------+------------------+-----+--------+
    # |              abc|                10|07/25|      10|
    # +-----------------+------------------+-----+--------+

    #calculate single parent many child dataframe
    df2_2_gre_1 = df2_c.where(F.col("order_count")>1)\
        .withColumn("aggregatedOrderId", F.concat(F.col("aggregatedOrderId"), F.lit('.'), F.col("r_no")))\
        .withColumn("totalOrderQuantity", F.lit(''))\
        .select("aggregatedOrderId", "totalOrderQuantity", F.col("ETA_c").alias("ETA"), F.col("Quantity_c").alias("quantity"))

    single_record = df2_c.where(F.col("order_count")==1).select("aggregatedOrderId").collect()
    single_record_final = [r['aggregatedOrderId'] for r in single_record]

    df1_without_single_record = df1_1.filter(~F.col("aggregatedOrderId_par").isin(single_record_final))\
    .select(F.col("aggregatedOrderId_par").alias("aggregatedOrderId"), "totalOrderQuantity", "ETA", "quantity")

    df_multi_union = df1_without_single_record.union(df2_2_gre_1)
    df_multi_union.show()

    df_final = df_multi_union.union(df_single_final)

    # +-----------------+------------------+-----+--------+
    # |aggregatedOrderId|totalOrderQuantity|  ETA|quantity|
    # +-----------------+------------------+-----+--------+
    # |              xyz|                20|     |        |
    # |            xyz.1|                  |08/01|      10|
    # |            xyz.2|                  |08/05|      10|
    # +-----------------+------------------+-----+--------+

    df_final.show()

    # +-----------------+------------------+-----+--------+
    # |aggregatedOrderId|totalOrderQuantity|  ETA|quantity|
    # +-----------------+------------------+-----+--------+
    # |              xyz|                20|     |        |
    # |            xyz.1|                  |08/01|      10|
    # |            xyz.2|                  |08/05|      10|
    # |              abc|                10|07/25|      10|
    # +-----------------+------------------+-----+--------+
```

Comment: @swty, can you post your ordersplits output as well to be clear. I did till the output you posted in question.

Answer (score 1):

As my knowledge of *pyspark* is **very** limited, I will show you how
to do your task in pure *pandasonic* way.

The idea is to group *df2* by *aggregatedOrderId* and apply a function
to each group.

This function must have 2 variants: *single-row* and *muliti-row*.

The *single-row* case boils down to just returning the original group
(a single row) with changed column order and *Quantity* repeated as
*totalOrderQuantity* and inserted in the right place.

The *multi-row* case involves concatenation of respective row from *df1*
and "reformatted" content of the current group.

To do it, define the following reformatting function:

```
def reformat(grp):
    grpSiz = grp.index.size
    if grpSiz == 1:    # Single-row case
        grp2 = grp[['aggregatedOrderId', 'ETA', 'Quantity']]
        grp2.insert(1, 'totalOrderQuantity', grp2.Quantity)
        return grp2
    # Multi-row case
    grp1 = (grp.aggregatedOrderId + [ f'.{n}' for n in range(
        1, grpSiz + 1)]).to_frame().assign(totalOrderQuantity='')\
        .join(grp[['ETA', 'Quantity']])
    return pd.concat([df1[df1.aggregatedOrderId ==  grp.iloc[0,0]], grp1])
```

Then apply it to each group from *df2*:

```
df2.groupby('aggregatedOrderId', sort=False).apply(reformat).reset_index(drop=True)
```

The final step (*reset_index*) is required to get rid of a MultiIndex created
by *groupby* and create a default index instead.

For your sample data the result is:

```
  aggregatedOrderId totalOrderQuantity    ETA Quantity
0               xyz                 20                
1             xyz.1                     08/01       10
2             xyz.2                     08/25       10
3               abc                 10  07/25       10
```

I think, my code is shorter that the *pyspark* way presented in the other
solution, so maybe it is worth to use only *Pandas* instead of *pyspark*.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the order splits as

```
df4 = final_df.withColumn('orderSplits',f.array(f.struct(*final_df.columns)))
df4.printSchema()

root
 |-- aggregatedOrderId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- totalOrderQuantity: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ETA: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Quantity: string (nullable = true)
 |-- orderSplits: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- aggregatedOrderId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- totalOrderQuantity: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ETA: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Quantity: string (nullable = true)


df4.show()

+-----------------+------------------+-----+--------+---------------------+
|aggregatedOrderId|totalOrderQuantity|ETA  |Quantity|orderSplits          |
+-----------------+------------------+-----+--------+---------------------+
|abc              |10                |     |10      |[[abc, 10, , 10]]    |
|xyz              |20                |     |        |[[xyz, 20, , ]]      |
|xyz.1            |null              |08/01|10      |[[xyz.1,, 08/01, 10]]|
|xyz.2            |null              |08/25|10      |[[xyz.2,, 08/25, 10]]|
+-----------------+------------------+-----+--------+---------------------+
```

Hope it helps